Variable not defined after using "global" keyword
I am trying to make rock paper scissors with a Tkinter GUI, but for some reason in my "run" function (unfinished) player_number is undefined,
def run():
    result.grid(column=3, row=1)
    if player_number == "1":
        rock.grid(column=2, row=2)


add_fillers()
choose_player_number()
run()

even though I defined it in these two functions (triggered by buttons) further up in the code:
def oneplayer():
    title.configure(text = "One player")
    title.grid(column=3, row=0)
    global player_number
    player_number = "1"
    one_player.destroy()
    two_players.destroy()


def twoplayers():
    title.configure(text = "Two players")
    title.grid(column=3, row=0)
    global player_number
    player_number = "2"
    one_player.destroy()
    two_players.destroy()

I tried setting the variables to global but that didn't work. Here's all my code:
import random
from random import randint
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1400x860")
window.title = "Rock paper scissors"

result = Label(window, text= "result will appear here", bg="green")

def oneplayer():
    title.configure(text = "One player")
    title.grid(column=3, row=0)
    global player_number
    player_number = "1"
    one_player.destroy()
    two_players.destroy()


def twoplayers():
    title.configure(text = "Two players")
    title.grid(column=3, row=0)
    global player_number
    player_number = "2"
    one_player.destroy()
    two_players.destroy()

one_player = Button(window, text = "One Player", command = oneplayer)
two_players = Button(window, text= "Two players", command = twoplayers)

title = Label(window, text = "Rock paper scissors" , bg= "blue", fg = "white", font= "Times")
title.grid(column=3, row=0)


def add_fillers():
    filler = Label(window, text = "                                                                   ")
    filler.grid(column=1, row=0)
    filler2 = Label(window, text = "                                                                   ")
    filler2.grid(column=0, row=0)
    filler3 = Label(window, text = "                                       ")
    filler3.grid(column=2, row=0)

def choose_player_number():
    one_player.grid(column= 2, row=1)
    two_players.grid(column= 4, row=1)
    
computer_input = ""

def computer_choice():
    computer_input = randint("1", "2", "3")
    if computer_input == "1":
        computer_value = "Rock"
    elif computer_input == "2":
        computer_value = "paper"
    else:
        computer_value = "scissors"
    computer_result = Label(window, text= "the computer's choice was:" + computer_value)

    return computer_input

def win():
    result.configure(text= "You Win")

def loose():
    result.configure(text= "You loose")

def draw():
    result.configure(text= "Draw")

def evaluate_rock():
    computer_choice()
    if computer_input == "3":
        win()
    elif computer_input == "2":
        loose()
    elif computer_input == "1":
        draw()
    else:
        print ("error")

rock = Button(window, text="Rock", command= evaluate_rock, fg="green", bg="blue")


def run():
    result.grid(column=3, row=1)
    if player_number == "1":
        rock.grid(column=2, row=2)


add_fillers()
choose_player_number()
run()

window.mainloop()



Neither of oneplayer or twoplayers is being called before run is, so effectively global player_number isn't being executed.

choose_player_number does not really do much, it just places the buttons, but then run() is called before the user can actually push those buttons.


I am trying to make rock paper scissors with a Tkinter GUI, but for
some reason in my "run" function (unfinished) player_number is
undefined,

The problem can be fixed.
Just add the parameter player_number to the run() function.
Snippet:
def run(player_number):
    result.grid(column=3, row=1)
    if player_number == "1":
        rock.grid(column=2, row=2)


add_fillers()
choose_player_number()
run(1)

Screenshot:


You pass an integer 1 to run(), but check for string "1" inside the function.

Yes, but OP is not finished yet. How will the user select one player or two players?

It is nothing related to OP, it is your provided solution that doesn't make sense.

Solution - Incomplete
I have corrected the code to solve your existing problem. As your code itself is incomplete, I didn't work further to make it complete. Also, this will make you to complete the code with your own idea.
What I've done
player_number, result, one_player, two_players, title and rock were the global variables in your code. As it is not advisable to use global variables, I've made the above variable names as the keys of a dict. Their values - I've made as the respective values of the same dict. As and when we need to call the value, I've called like dct['variable_name']. Using this method, we can easily avoid using global keyword. (Just check whether the variable computer_input needs to be declared global. If so, you can do this in the same way I did.)
You should work on the rest of the code with the idea and logics you have in your mind.
import random
from random import randint
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

dct = {'player_number' : ''}

def run():
    dct['result'].grid(column=3, row=1)
    if dct['player_number'] == "1":
        dct['rock'].grid(column=2, row=2)

def oneplayer():
    dct['title'].configure(text = "One player")
    dct['title'].grid(column=3, row=0)
    
    dct['player_number'] = "1"
    dct['one_player'].destroy()
    dct['two_players'].destroy()


def twoplayers():
    dct['title'].configure(text = "Two players")
    dct['title'].grid(column=3, row=0)
    
    dct['player_number'] = "2"
    dct['one_player'].destroy()
    dct['two_players'].destroy()

def add_fillers():
    filler = Label(window, text = "")                                                       
    filler.grid(column=1, row=0)
    filler2 = Label(window, text = "")                                                                  
    filler2.grid(column=0, row=0)
    filler3 = Label(window, text = "")                                      
    filler3.grid(column=2, row=0)

def choose_player_number():
    dct['one_player'].grid(column= 2, row=1)
    dct['two_players'].grid(column= 4, row=1)
    
def computer_choice():
    computer_input = randint("1", "2", "3")
    if computer_input == "1":
        computer_value = "Rock"
    elif computer_input == "2":
        computer_value = "paper"
    else:
        computer_value = "scissors"
    computer_result = Label(window, text= "the computer's choice was:" + computer_value)

    return computer_input

def win():
    dct['result'].configure(text= "You Win")

def loose():
    dct['result'].configure(text= "You loose")

def draw():
    dct['result'].configure(text= "Draw")

def evaluate_rock():
    computer_choice()
    if computer_input == "3":
        win()
    elif computer_input == "2":
        loose()
    elif computer_input == "1":
        draw()
    else:
        print ("error")

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry("1400x860")
window.title = "Rock paper scissors"


dct['result'] = Label(window, text= "result will appear here", bg="green")

dct['one_player'] = Button(window, text = "One Player", command = oneplayer)
dct['two_players'] = Button(window, text= "Two players", command = twoplayers)

dct['title'] = Label(window, text = "Rock paper scissors" , bg= "blue", fg = "white", font= "Times")
dct['title'].grid(column=3, row=0)

dct['rock'] = Button(window, text="Rock", command= evaluate_rock, fg="green", bg="blue")


add_fillers()
choose_player_number()
run()

window.mainloop()


Global variables are inadvisable in OOP but in procedural programming, they are necessary most of the time. Right now the global dictionary named dct acts the same way as a global namespace would.

@TheLizzard, The line between "procedural" and "object oriented" may be fuzzier than you think. Unless you're dealing with a truly ancient language that has no struct and no pointers or references, it's quite easy to write meaningful procedural programs in which all of the data are accessed via references/pointers that are passed up and down the stack. It's equally easy (in all of the "object oriented" languages that I've ever used) to declare static/global variables. But, you're right. From a software engineer's perspective, global variables are bad in any programming paradigm.
